# On hover only display child element with common class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="example">
 <div class="test" style="display:none;">Text</div>
</div>

<div class="example">
 <div class="test" style="display:none;">Some other text</div>
</div>
```

When an element with the class `example` is hovered over, it'll show its child element with the class `text` (possibly with a simple `.show()` and `.hide()` in jQuery).

I need it to show only its child element and not other elements with the class `test`. How can I do this without specifying `id`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div.example").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("div.test").show();
},function(){
    $(this).find("div.test").hide();
});
```

Hope you are looking for this.

You can check a [***working demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/tastr/)

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, [you can even do it in CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/kdr2j/):

```
.test{                   //or .example .test {}
    display:none;
}

.example:hover .test{
    display:block;      //block or inline, your call
}
```